# If there are two events within a single payable function, is it guaranteed to have same transactionHash for both event logs?

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, web3.py

I have a simple contract that emits two events when the `purchase` function is called.

```
contract OwnedToken {
   ...

   function purchase(tokenId) public payable{
       ...
       FirstEvent(...);
       ...
       SecondEvent(...);
       ...
   }
   ...
}
```

I tested it on Rinkeby network and logs for both `FirstEvent` and `SecondEvent` seem to have same `transactionHash` & `blockNumber`.

Is it guaranteed to have same `transactionHash` for both above event logs even in the MainNet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both events will have the same `transactionHash`: they are both triggered by the same, single transaction.  This example assumes that there is no conditional logic that might only emit one of the events.